Must the number of orderer node in smartBFT be at least 4?
I'm trying to understand the smartBFT and RAFT consensus protocols in the Hyperledger Fabric. As you know, starting from Fabric v3.0, smartBFT can be used as an ordered type. I checked the official Hyperledger Fabric test network files and saw four orderers in their example. Is this some kind of obligation? If I want to see the performance of RAFT and smartBFT, should I also create four orderers for the RAFT-based network? This can be a silly question but I want to know the logic.

Raft requires a majority of nodes for consensus. Five nodes is often chosen since the network can then tolerate two nodes failing and still have a majority (of three) for consensus. Three nodes are required to tolerate a single node failure.
The Fabric BFT implementation can tolerate failure of up to (but not including) one third of the nodes. The network is unable to reach consensus if a third or more of the nodes fail. That means you need at least four nodes to be able to tolerate a node failure.
BFT can tolerate not only ordering node failures, but also malicious / compromised ordering nodes, which Raft cannot. This means that the two are not directly comparable based only on the number of failed nodes they can tolerate.
There is more detailed information in the Fabric ordering service documentation.

So, what is the right way to compare these two consensus algorithms? I think both should be tested in the same environment in terms of network structure (such as number of orderers, organizations, and peers etc.). Am I wrong?

I agree that comparable configurations make more meaningful performance comparisons. You could use a single orderer but it's not very realistic. You could configure the minimal number to tolerate a single node failure (3 for Raft, 4 for BFT). You might chose a configuration that best represents what you would want to run in production. Just bear in mind that performance is not the only difference since BFT gives you resilience to a class of failures that a comparable Raft network does not.

Yes,BFT has exact advantages against Raft. As you mentioned,in the Raft protocol,one must run 2F+1 nodes to withstand F (CFT) failures. The minimal fault tolerant deployment is 3 nodes. In SmartBFT,one must run 3F+1 nodes to withstand F (BFT) failures. This means that the minimal fault tolerant deployment is 4 nodes. However, I am still confused about whether 1 extra orderer (using 4 orderers instead of 3 for Raft) could provide the slightest advantages for Raft. I want to create the most accurate environment for the most accurate comparison.
